# Laravel Socialize giving undefined access_token

Tags: oauth, laravel-5

I followed the laracasts tutorial on Socialite with Laravel 5.0 and I ran in to the below error.  It occurred after logging in to GitHub and being redirected.  I don't know how Socialize works on the back end.

```
ErrorException in AbstractProvider.php line 257:

Undefined index: access_token in AbstractProvider.php line 257
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: access_token',
'/home/vagrant/blog/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php', 
'257', array('body' => object(Stream))) in AbstractProvider.php line 257
at AbstractProvider->parseAccessToken(object(Stream)) in 
AbstractProvider.php line 232
at AbstractProvider->getAccessToken('d21bd355569b6249cfd3') in 
AbstractProvider.php line 195
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find anything after googling around, but I eventually was able to find the line where the error was thrown.  I printed the body and saw an error.

```
protected function parseAccessToken($body)
{
    dd(json_decode($body, true));
    return json_decode($body, true)['access_token'];
}
```

My error was:

```
"error" => "incorrect_client_credentials"
"error_description" => "The client_id and/or client_secret passed are incorrect."
"error_uri" => "https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#incorrect-client-credentials"
```

I discovered that in the `config/services.php` file I mistyped `env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET');` so it was returning an empty string which is why there was a mismatch.  The same can happen with any errors.  Just do a `dd(json_decode($body,true));` to see what the error was.